# How to run macro in multiple workbooks with one sheet filter criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run macro from file "A: that include Sheet named "Filter_Criteria" on multiple Worksheets from specific folder.
In each "B%" Worksheet from selected folder data from Sheet "Data" shall be filtered by range Sheet "Filter_Criteria" from file A and send back to Sheet "Output" file "B%".
Issue is that non of files from folder is being filtered and I got to results in any "B%" Worksheet.

Macro goes from the beginning to the end with no issues.
Inside-macro code works fine while running it on each file with:

```
Set Data_sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set Output_sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
```

But I cannot understand what is wrong with current changes.

```
Sub RunOnAllFilesInFolder()
    Dim folderName As String, eApp As Excel.Application, fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, currWs As Worksheet, currWb As Workbook
    Dim fDialog As Object: Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    Dim Filter_Criteria_Sh As Worksheet
    Set currWb = ActiveWorkbook: Set currWs = ActiveSheet
    Set Filter_Criteria_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")

    'Folder with Worksheets
    fDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = currWb.Path
    If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
      folderName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If


    'New Excel Process
    Set eApp = New Excel.Application:  eApp.Visible = False


    fileName = Dir(folderName & "\*.*")
    Do While fileName <> ""
        'Update status bar to indicate progress
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & folderName & "\" & fileName


        Set wb = eApp.Workbooks.Open(folderName & "\" & fileName)

'Filter Data Macro

Dim Data_sh As Worksheet
Dim Output_sh As Worksheet


Set Data_sh = wb.Sheets("Data")
Set Output_sh = wb.Sheets("Output")

Output_sh.UsedRange.Clear


Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim Emp_list() As String
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Filter_Criteria_Sh.Range("A:A")) - 2

ReDim Emp_list(n) As String

Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To n
    Emp_list(i) = Filter_Criteria_Sh.Range("A" & i + 2)
Next i


Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, Emp_list(), xlFilterValues
Data_sh.UsedRange.Copy Output_sh.Range("A1")

Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False


MsgBox ("Data has been Copied")

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False 
        Debug.Print "Processed " & folderName & "\" & fileName
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
    eApp.Quit
    Set eApp = Nothing
    'Clear statusbar and notify of macro completion
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox "Completed executing macro on all workbooks"
End Sub
```

I expect that 'Filter Data Macro will filter data in each file with filter criteria stored in Worksheet "A"

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating a new instance of excel to open the workbooks?  And don't you want to save the changes?  `wb.Close SaveChanges:=False` will not save anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

You're not saving any changes you make to the workbooks.

Comment: Yes sir, thank you so much.
I left that as "False" during first test and totaly forgot about it in my Friday rush.